# I am unable to get response data or response body

Tags: cookies, jmeter, token, csrf

I ran my jmeter script, but i am getting this message in my response data.

> for(;;);[{"changes":{},"resources":{},"locales":{},"meta":{"appError":{"caption":"Cookies disabled","url":null,"message":"This application requires cookies to function.
> Please enable cookies in your browser and click here or press ESC to try again.","details":null,"querySelector":null}},"syncId":-1}]

[image]

I was expecting a response body or data to be displayed after running the script. I have a feeling it has to do with the Cookie or token.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have any cookies for the very first request. The whole idea of cookies is:

- When you open a web page (or perform login) server sends a small piece of information to your via [Set-Cookie header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) and browser stores it internally
- One the next request to that page browser sends the cookie via [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) header and if the cookie is valid, correct, not expired, etc. it will be used by the server for identifying the user (or other purposes like tracking)

Since you haven't performed any requests so far JMeter impersonates a "new" user who opens the page first time in his life hence it cannot have any cookies.

So most probably this request should not be the first in your test plan, in this case you will need to re-order HTTP Request samplers (for example put this one after the login) and [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-cookie-manager) will do the rest

Comment: This request is the first and I am getting the same response data for all the request.

Comment: i am getting                                                                                                                 
                        for(;;);[{"changes":{},"resources":{},"locales":{},"meta":{"appError":{"caption":"Cookies disabled","url":null,"message":"This application requires cookies to function.<br>Please enable cookies in your browser and <u>click here</u> or press ESC to try again.","details":null,"querySelector":null}},"syncId":-1}]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem. You need to supply the cookie with each request. You can get the current session cookie by just doing a GET, POST, etc with Firefox Dev tools or something else,and paste it into the request body. Worked fine after that. I experimented with the cookie by deliberately chopping a couple of characters off, then it came back and said my session was expired, so it not only was demanding the cookie, but the correct cookie. Some servers also require the CSRF token, and some servers may even change the cookie with each request. I was lucky, as my server just used the same cookie for the entire session.